# memory leak in pictureBox Image

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, memory-leaks, picturebox

I have made a program in which I am changing image of picturebox again an again using this code

```
while(1)
{
    this->pictureBox1->Refresh();
    System::Drawing::Bitmap ^bmp;
    bmp=drawImageMeter(data.Max);
    this->pictureBox1->Image =pictureBox1->Image->FromHbitmap(bmp->GetHbitmap());
    delete bmp;
}
```

`drawImageMeter(data.Max);` is function which is making bitmap and returning it.

My problem is that it is showing memory leak on this line

```
this->pictureBox1->Image =pictureBox1->Image->FromHbitmap(bmp->GetHbitmap());
```

Intel Vtune is showing this leak on the same line::

```
P810        Memory leak form2.h  Form1.exe  808 New

P34     Kernel resource leak    form2.h  Form1.exe      Not fixed
```

Edited Code...

```
delete pictureBox1->Image;
pictureBox1->Image=nullptr;
this->pictureBox1->Refresh();                   
bmp=drawImageMeter(data.Max);
System::IntPtr hbitmap = bmp->GetHbitmap();
this->pictureBox1->Image =pictureBox1->Image->FromHbitmap(hbitmap);//Memory LEAK & Kernel Resource Leak
delete bmp;
DeleteObject((HGDIOBJ)hbitmap );
```

After that I am not getting GDI resource leak but still getting Memory leak on this line..

```
this->pictureBox1->Image =pictureBox1->Image->FromHbitmap(hbitmap);//Memory LEAK
```

**drawImageMeter() Definition**

```
System::Drawing::Bitmap^ drawImageMeter(float intensity_value)
{
    IplImage  *Background=cvLoadImage("Dialer.bmp", 1); //Memory Leak
        int width,height;
        width=Background->width;
        height=Background->height;
        if(counter==1)
        {
            counter++;
        needle_center.x=width/2;
        needle_center.y=height/2; 
        needle_top.x=needle_center.x;
        needle_top.y=needle_center.y-140;
        }
        double const PI = 3.14159265358979323;
           int x1 = needle_top.x; 
           int y1 = needle_top.y;

           int x0=needle_center.x;
           int y0=needle_center.y;
           float angle;
            CurrIntensity = intensity_value;
            angle = CurrIntensity-PreIntensity;
            angle= 0.0703125f * angle;
           // degrees, not radians
           float radians = angle * (PI / 180.0f);   // convert degrees to radians
           if (current_max==1)
            {
                current_max++;
                int N1x1 = needle_top.x; 
                int N1y1 = needle_top.y;
                needle1_top.x = ((N1x1-x0) * cos(radians)) - ((N1y1-y0) * sin(radians)) + x0; 
                needle1_top.y = ((N1x1-x0) * sin(radians)) + ((N1y1-y0) * cos(radians)) + y0;
            }
           needle_top.x = ((x1-x0) * cos(radians)) - ((y1-y0) * sin(radians)) + x0; 
           needle_top.y = ((x1-x0) * sin(radians)) + ((y1-y0) * cos(radians)) + y0;

           cvLine(Background, needle_center, needle1_top, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), 1, 4, 0);

           cvLine(Background, needle_center, needle_top, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 4, 0);
         System::Drawing::Bitmap ^bmp = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(Background->width,Background->height,Background->widthStep,System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)Background->imageData);
         PreIntensity = CurrIntensity;
         return bmp;
    }
```

In this function I am getting memory leak on this line where I have written //Memory Leak.
I can not release this IplImage  *Background here in this function if I'll release this image here so i'll not be able to see image in pitureBox and doing this application is being closed.

Can anybody please help me sort out this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: The FromHbitmap method makes a copy of the bitmap; so you should release the incoming GDI bitmap using the DeleteObject method immediately after creating the new Image.

Comment: @MarsRover Thanks for reply...I have edited my code according to you and not getting any GDI leak but still getting Memory Leak on same line.